# Check if date range is available

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an array of object consisting of checkin and checkout date values. I need to be able to iterate through this array to check if current booking date overlaps with dates in the array.

**Model**

```
const ReservationSchema = new Schema({
 startDate: {type: Date, required: true},
 endDate: {type: Date, required: true},
 property: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Property'}
});
```

**My initial query**

const reservations = await Reservation.find({ property: propertyId }).where('startDate').lte(moment(req.body.endDate)).where('endDate').gte(moment(req.body.startDate)).select('startDate endDate').exec();

**Previously saved records**

[{id: 123, startDate: "2019-6-01", endDate: "2019-06-04}, {id: 124, startDate: "2019-6-03", endDate: "2019-06-10}, {id: 125, startDate: "2019-6-09", endDate: "2019-06-12}]

I expect two different results: 1) an array of all the bookings that fall with the dates provided. 2) a boolean value if the date range is available to book.

Comment: Ideal way is to have this logic server-side, not as a front-end validation using JavaScript

Comment: This is done on the server using mongoose, I failed to mention that.

Comment: can you add model in question..? so that exact query i can provide.!
You said dates are in array and in given query you are checking directly with startDate and endDate. Update question with model or one data from collection.

Comment: question has been update